# What is manifest in HTML5 ? and how to use it?

Tags: html

I want the page visible to the user even when the net connection breaks so is there a way to
store the page for atleast some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describing the cache manifest in an SO answer will take a lot of space.  Instead of doing that, I'm going to save everyone some time and post a tutorial for you: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

StackOverflow is better suited if you have trouble understanding a specific part of cache manifests.

Comment: Thank you John that link is very useful...